# Perplexing .htaccess/PHP Conundrum

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, permissions

So... I finished a site on my local server, and I uploaded it to my remote server.

Going to the remote site yields an Internal Server error. I think there might be something wrong with the `.htaccess` file. Here's what it contains:

```
Options All -Indexes  
Options +FollowSymlinks  
DirectoryIndex launcher.php  
IndexIgnore */*  
RewriteEngine ON  
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.less$ $1.css.php [nc]  
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z]+)$ launcher.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Eventually, I tried to debug the problem by adding `#` before the DirectoryIndex line to see what would happen. The result:

> 403 Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /site/ on this server.

Which is puzzling, because all the permissions seem to be ok... I double checked, the `.htaccess` file has octal 644.

What could be causing this issue? Thanks for any responses in advance.

Comment: Maybe mod_rewrite is not active on the server?

Comment: If the 500 error was really caused by a bum .htaccess, check the error log for more information.  Apache is usually pretty good at explaining when something went wrong in a config file / .htaccess.

Comment: I think the default error_log is usually at /var/logs/apache2/error_log

Comment: I thought of this, however, even though I don't have access to httpd.conf, I've utilized `mod_rewrite` on other scripts on this server successfully.

Comment: If commenting out DirectoryIndex says 403 forbidden, it's because Options Indexes is off. That's fine. It would seem to indicate an error in launcher.php. As usual, looking in the server error log is critical.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, checked the log: `"Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /home/user/public_html/site/"`. I'm wondering why I'm getting this error, as I'm currently using `Options -Indexes` to prevent unauthorized file browsing.

Comment: After commenting out *both* Options lines, I get the 500 ISE, and here's the error for that: `"SoftException in Application.cpp:256: File "/home/user/public_html/site/launcher.php" is writeable by group`"

Comment: Where is `.htaccess` placed? It the root or in `/site/`? If it's in the root, does an actual folder called `/site/` exist?

Comment: There you go. You probably have `664` permissions on that file instead of `644`.

Comment: Yes, a folder called "site" exists, and it's in the root of "/site".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the help SO users, my problem was solved.

Apparently, Apache freaks out if the `.htaccess` file has permissions set to write, so I was able to fix the problem by `chmod`ing the entire directory and everything in it to 755.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and as the error message says, the file mentioned was having permission `664`. I just removed the write permission for group and the permission became `644`. That fixed the error.